# How to hide query string from url in spring mvc.?

Tags: spring-mvc

i try to hide query string from URL it work success but problem is that when i refresh page it will give error like "the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
</script>
```

i use this script to hide Query string in URL.